# Laravel One to One several columns with same relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, laravel-5

I've been tasked with building a website given a database that's already in place, using laravel. I'm not able to make any changes to the database structure, as the system is currently in production.

There are two tables: `Item` and `Transaction`. A `Transaction` has a predefined number of items available for it `[Item1...Item8]` listed in their own *separate* columns.

I know I can specify in the model to do a:

```
function item1() {
    $this->hasOne('App\Item', 'item_key', 'item1');
}
```

For each of the columns within the transaction model.

Is there an easier way to concatenate the items together and give me an array?

Like...

```
function items() {
   $this->hasOne('App\Item', 'item_key', ['item1','item2'....]);
}
```

***Edit:*** 
I am aware I could pull each `item` individually through the `items()` method and create the array myself. Just wondering if Laravel provides a helper for it.

Comment: AFAIK I doubt there is anything else that would let the relation work. I'm not even sure it will actually work in any way, considering you have multiple columns to refer to.

Comment: does the original database have proper relationships set up?

Comment: @DevDonkey yes it does

Comment: That's look like a denormalized DB, it's unlikely such a situation will ever be supported/implemented by design